# What is wrong with this code? I am trying to find the width of each items image, if the image is a certain width, apply a class to that item

Tags: jquery, each

```
$(window).load(function() { 
    $('#grid .item').each(function() {
        var imageH = $(this).children('img').attr('width');

            if(imageH = 506) {
                $(this).addClass('d');
            } else if (imageH = 250) {
                $(this).addClass('a');
            }
    });
});
```

The page is here - http://stable.dev.pixel-geeks.co.uk/news/

I am trying to create a dynamic grid in Wordpress. I require the system to see that a certain image size has been uploaded, if that image size meets certain criteria then apply a class to the container of that image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be

```
if(imageH == 506) {
    $(this).addClass('d');
} else if (imageH == 250) {
    $(this).addClass('a');
}
```

You are **not comparing**,you are **assigning** to `imageH` which will always return `true`

Comment: Thank you! Simple mistake, I appreciate your time.. Will accept once 10 mins has passed.. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

While you can get the width using `attr()`, if there is a width attribute on the image, there is a specific jQuery method for this

Use `var imageH = $(this).children('img').width();`

Also, you only have single equals in your if statements, `if (imageH = 506)` should be `if (imageH == 506)`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer, the problem with this is that the sizes are only gained after the images have finished loading.. With the attr method the sizes are gained at document ready which was what was needed.